# send jquery variable to express.js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have acquired a product-id from jquery :

                `jQuery('#button').click(function (event) {
                console.log (event.target.id);
                });`

and I need to get that id value in the nodejs server.

How can i do this?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've thought of using socket.io but I need a simpler way 
`socket.emit('IdproductToUpdate',event.target.id);`

Comment: `console.log ('event.target.id');` will log `event.target.id` as string, replace it with `console.log (event.target.id);` Not there are no quotes

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why you would like to use the element id, but here you go:

You need to make an xhr request with jquery as you already use it and send it to your nodejs server. Then handling the request with an express route as a body value and do whatever you want.

Ajax request:

```
var data = {};
data.id = myid;
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: success,
 dataType: dataType
});
```

And your express route

```
app.post('/myroutename', function(req,res,next,) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    // then do whatever you want with your id
});
```

But i suggest you to read more about [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and [JQuery post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually I need the id of a button because it contains the product id so for instance when user clicks on the update button the button's id (product id) will get to the server so I could be able to use the `findOneAndUpdate` function of mongo